# nginx showing IP address instead of domain

Tags: nginx, dns

I have a godaddy A record pointing to my Digital Ocean IP address.

Here's the nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    location / {
       proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:3004';
    }
}
```

When I type in the `domain.com` it goes to the server, but the address bar shows the IP address.

How can it show the domain name?

Comment: same configuration exactly...same problem. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't remember. I think it resolved itself somehow.

Answer (score 2):

It's most probably a redirection from proxy_pass. I'm not sure what you are running at backend but you could try to pass hostname.

```
proxy_set_header Host      $host;
```

Add this line after proxy_pass to tell backend which domain is in the request headers.

Comment: I'm using node express. Your suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: You should track which part does the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection to the IP address is *most likely* done by your backend in the `proxy_pass`. 
You could try to add some header to help the backend understand the context of the request.

I would recommend as a starter the following configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;


    location / {
       proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:3004';
    }
}
```

If using Node.JS, you might need the following line as well :

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
```

Please also check the configuration of your backend. You may need to setup the access URL, context path, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly, this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming from Godaddy's default forwarding configurations. You must talk to their support team to make the necessary changes. That is how I resolved the same issue with them.